# Confusion in the calculation of hidden layer size in CNN

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am trying to understand the convolutional neural network. I am reading the book deep learning by grokking. Here is the code that they have written.

```
import numpy as np, sys
np.random.seed(1)

from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

images, labels = (x_train[0:1000].reshape(1000, 28*28)/255, y_train[0:1000])

one_hot_labels = np.zeros((len(labels), 10))

for i, l in enumerate(labels):
    one_hot_labels[i][l] = 1
labels = one_hot_labels

test_images = x_test.reshape(len(x_test), 28*28) / 255
test_labels = np.zeros((len(y_test), 10))
for i, l in enumerate(y_test):
    test_labels[i][l] = 1

def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)

def tanh2deriv(output):
    return 1 - (output ** 2)

def softmax(x):
    temp = np.exp(x)
    return temp/np.sum(temp, axis=1, keepdims=True)

alpha, iterations = (2, 30)
pixels_per_image, num_labels = (784, 10)
batch_size = 128

input_rows = 28
input_cols = 28

kernel_rows = 3
kernel_cols = 3
num_kernels = 16

hidden_size = ((input_rows - kernel_rows)*(input_cols - kernel_cols))*num_kernels

kernels = 0.02*np.random.random((kernel_rows*kernel_cols, num_kernels))-0.01

weights_1_2 = 0.02*np.random.random((hidden_size, num_labels))-0.1

def get_image_section(layer, row_from, row_to, col_from, col_to):
    section = layer[:, row_from:row_to, col_from:col_to]
    return section.reshape(-1,1, row_to-row_from,col_to-col_from)

for j in range(iterations):
    correct_cnt = 0
    for i in range(int(len(images)/batch_size)):
        batch_start, batch_end = ((i*batch_size), ((i+1)*batch_size))
        layer_0 = images[batch_start:batch_end]
        layer_0 = layer_0.reshape(layer_0.shape[0], 28, 28)
        # print(layer_0.shape)

        sects = list()
        for row_start in range(layer_0.shape[1]-kernel_rows):
            for col_start in range(layer_0.shape[2]-kernel_cols):
                sect = get_image_section(layer_0, row_start, row_start+kernel_rows, col_start, col_start+kernel_cols)
                sects.append(sect)
        
        expanded_input = np.concatenate(sects, axis=1)
        es = expanded_input.shape
        flattened_input = expanded_input.reshape(es[0]*es[1], -1)

        kernel_output = flattened_input.dot(kernels)
        layer_1 = tanh(kernel_output.reshape(es[0], -1))
        dropout_mask = np.random.randint(2, size=layer_1.shape)
        layer_1 *= dropout_mask*2
        layer_2 = softmax(np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2))

        for k in range(batch_size):
            labelset = labels[batch_start+k:batch_start+k+1]
            _inc = int(np.argmax(layer_2[k:k+1]) == np.argmax(labelset))
            correct_cnt += _inc

        layer_2_delta = (labels[batch_start:batch_end]-layer_2)/(batch_size*layer_2.shape[0])
        layer_1_delta = layer_2_delta.dot(weights_1_2.T)*tanh2deriv(layer_1)
        layer_1_delta *= dropout_mask

        weights_1_2 += alpha*layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)

        l1d_reshape = layer_1_delta.reshape(kernel_output.shape)
        k_update = flattened_input.T.dot(l1d_reshape)
        kernels -= alpha*k_update

    test_correct_cnt = 0

    for i in range(len(test_images)):
        layer_0 = test_images[i:i+1]
        layer_0 = layer_0.reshape(layer_0.shape[0], 28, 28)

        sects = list()

        for row_start in range(layer_0.shape[1]-kernel_rows):
            for col_start in range(layer_0.shape[2]-kernel_cols):
                sect = get_image_section(layer_0, row_start, row_start+kernel_rows, col_start, col_start+kernel_rows)
                sects.append(sect)
        
        expanded_input = np.concatenate(sects, axis=1)
        es = expanded_input.shape
        flattened_input = expanded_input.reshape(es[0]*es[1], -1)

        kernel_output = flattened_input.dot(kernels)
        layer_1 = tanh(kernel_output.reshape(es[0], -1))
        layer_2 = np.dot(layer_1, weights_1_2)

        test_correct_cnt += int(np.argmax(layer_2) == np.argmax(test_labels[i:i+1]))
    if(j%10 == 0):
      print(f"I:{j} Test-Acc:{test_correct_cnt/float(len(test_images))} Train-Acc:{correct_cnt/float(len(images))}")
```

I am confused about the following line

```
hidden_size = ((input_rows - kernel_rows)*(input_cols - kernel_cols))*num_kernels
```

So, if I have a 5x5 image, 3x3 filter, 1 filter, 1 stride and no padding then according to this equation I should have hidden_size as 4. But If I do a convolution operation on paper then I am doing 9 convolution operations. So can anyone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1 there are also quite some known issues within the repository, so yo might be stumbling over some more while you go. Might be worth checking here 
 in future as well https://github.com/iamtrask/Grokking-Deep-Learning/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with that book, but the code you presented seems to ignore a column/row at the end. If you add +1 as shown below, you will get 9 convolution operations for a 5x5 image.

```py
# from
hidden_size = ((input_rows - kernel_rows)*(input_cols - kernel_cols))*num_kernels

# to
hidden_size = ((input_rows - kernel_rows + 1)*(input_cols - kernel_cols + 1))*num_kernels
```

```py
# This changes are required for both training and testing.
# from
        for row_start in range(layer_0.shape[1]-kernel_rows):
            for col_start in range(layer_0.shape[2]-kernel_cols):

# to
        for row_start in range(layer_0.shape[1]-kernel_rows + 1):
            for col_start in range(layer_0.shape[2]-kernel_cols + 1):
```

In case you didn't get what these changes were about, here are some animations to help you understand. Each cell represents a pixel in the image, and the red box represents the convolution kernel.

before:

[image: before]

after:

[image: after]